# A proposed criteria for whether something constitutes a real topic

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems like the question of "is *x* a real topic?" comes up quite often in discussions of whether or not to burninate tags. This is related to criteria #1 in [Shog9's rules for tag burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

My premise here is that the primary (or perhaps even sole) purpose of tags is to connect people who want to answer questions with questions that they're likely be able to answer (and hopefully that they find interesting/enjoyable to answer, too).

That being said, a frequently-used criteria is as follows:

> Can you be an expert on the topic?

If you can't be, odds are it's not a real topic.

I'd like to propose a closely related criteria:

> Would the presence or absence of this tag alter the probability of you knowing the answer to the question?

For example, if a question was tagged with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), it improves the odds that I'll know the answer because that's my primary programming language. If, however, it was tagged with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), it significantly *decreases* the chance that I'll know the answer (because I don't know PHP).

However, many tags are highly unlikely to make any difference in whether someone knows the answer. For example, [line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line), [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert), and [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entry) leap to mind as things that couldn't possibly make a difference in whether you're likely to know the answer or not. (Full disclosure: I do have burnination requests for [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) and [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entry). There's also a burnination request for [line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/line), but it's not mine).

I'd like to propose having this as a valid reason to burninate a tag. I think it's a good way to test whether a tag falls under @Shog9's first point in his Meta post.

**TL;DR** If the presence or absence of a particular tag doesn't change the odds of you knowing the answer to a question, then odds are it's not a real topic and should be burninated.

Comment: I think the `Would the presence or absence of this tag alter the probability of you knowing the answer to the question?` has the right idea, but it needs to be worded a little differently. The way it's worded sounds like the tags cause you to know the answer or not, but you're talking about a correlation between the accuracy of a tag. Perhaps `Does the presence of this tag invite people to the question who would be likely to be able to answer it?` or if anyone can come up with a better wording that doesn't make a "cause" based context.

Comment: This just gets so tiring. Do you want to make it where the only tags we have are for programming languages? What other tags would your overly-restrictive system endorse?

Comment: This is not the first post I've seen referencing Shog's guidelines but failing to actually read [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to which he links, the one that actually describes what Meta tags are. *"They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.)."*

Comment: @CodyGray No, not at all - there are plenty of other valid topics, like [data-structures], that you can know about that aren't about specific programming languages. My point is more that a tag should be something you can actually know about and that would actually help connect people with questions that they can answer. Also, I wasn't intending to imply that *all* questions that meet this criteria are Meta tags - I suppose that some of them would fall under his other criteria for being just plain old ambiguous, for example, or otherwise not real topics.

Comment: @DavyM Good point.

Comment: [data-structures] is vulnerable to exactly the same phenomenon you decry in this very question. If a question is tagged with [data-structures] and [php], then it's extremely unlikely that someone who doesn't know PHP will be able to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

While it is true that answerers use tags in order to find questions to answer, that only matters at the time of answering. After the question is answered and activity fades, we need to use tags to organize this giant library we're building. The majority of a question's life will be inactivity (at least as far as editing and answering go). There's no use in a database of solutions to common programming problems with no way to find that information later on.

That's why we *need* other tags that have less to do with connecting questions to experts for answers than they do with organizing questions. Yeah, [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) can't stand on it's own (bad example), and I can't imagine many people monitoring the live feed for such a tag waiting to pounce on the next question asked with an expert answer, *but* when you search for questions tagged both [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) and sort by votes ([example query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20AND%20%5bstring%5d)), you get a great list of the highest voted JavaScript questions about dealing with strings and you're much more likely to find the answer you're looking for than if you had just used the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.

We have to realize that Meta represents a given subset of active Stack Overflow users, but (if I recall correctly) the vast majority of Stack Overflow traffic comes from external links and people searching for solutions. That means that—from a traffic perspective—the primary purpose of tags is to organize questions in order to make finding them later easier. Connecting experts to questions is secondary to that.

Comment: I agree with this answer as a whole, but not necessarily the first bolded sentence. In fact, filtering by [javascript] and [string] *is* an important way that experts find/connect to questions. There is definitely a point to be made here, though, that tags are how we *categorize* things, and that serves a bit larger purpose than the obvious functional one of connecting experts to questions.

Comment: @CodyGray I think that's Tiny Giant's purpose in using the qualifier `Just`. Filtering by multiple tags is an important way that experts find/connect to questions, but it is also an important way that novices do it too, in fact, even more frequently novices put a whole sentence "My array of strings in java threw an error" And it hits the [array] [string] and [java] tags in their search. I agree with the bolded sentence, because it points out a very important use (For the experts) but emphasizes that that is not the *only* use we care about and not the *only* purpose for tags.

Comment: And that was my purpose in using the qualifier "necessarily". :-) At any rate, I'm not sure what you mean by the observation that novices type sentences into the tag box. That's absolutely true, but it's a bad thing and does not represent a good use of tags. @Davy

Answer (score -3):

No. The proposed test adds nothing. A statement such as

> if a question was tagged with c#, it improves the odds that I'll know
>   the answer because that's my primary programming language

can reasonably be construed to suggest that I (or any other SO user) might ask a question on, say, an abstruse corner of Fortran programming and then tag it `c#`, magically increasing the odds that you (the self-confessed `C#` programmer) can answer the question.  The odds that you can answer a particular question are not altered by the tags attached to it. The tags affect the odds that you will visit a question, but that's a different matter.

Of course, no sensible and attentive SO user is going to mis-tag a question about Fortran programming by attaching the `c#` tag, because such a tagging would fail the test

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
>   and is it unambiguous?

I don't see that the proposal actually adds anything useful in determining whether or not a particular tag should be burninated.  Or not.

Comment: Obviously, my assumption is that the tag actually accurately reflects the content. If they *had* tagged it properly (Fortran rather than C#), then obviously odds are I won't know the answer.